# QT Connect issue (subfunctions are not getting called in connect)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals

I'm using the Qt application. When I'm trying to call the subclass from the connect, subclass (doWork) function it's not getting called. please refer to my sample code and help me to solve the issue.

> I'm using the Qt application. When I'm trying to call the subclass from the connect, subclass (doWork) function it's not getting called. please refer to my sample code and help me to solve the issue.

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "QMainWindow"
#include <QThread>
#include "Worker.h"

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);    
    ~MainWindow(); private:  
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QThread *thread;
    Worker *worker;
signals:
    void requestUpdate(int initial);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    thread = new QThread();
    worker = new Worker();

    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(requestUpdate(int)), worker, SLOT(doWork(int)));

    int enc = 10;
    emit requestUpdate(enc);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete thread;
    delete worker;

    delete UI;
}
```

**Worker.h**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H

#define WORKER_H

#include<QObject>

class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void workRequested();

public slots:
    void doWork(int initial);
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
#include "Worker.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QEventLoop>

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{    
    _working =false;
    _abort = false;
}


void Worker::doWork(int initial)
{

qDebug() << "initial" << endl;

}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Haji

Comment: In the code shown you never call `thread->start()` in the `MainWindow` constructor.

Comment: Any new problems should be posted as a new/separate question on SO.